# Office 365 Web Add-in: Office.initialize() is not being called

Tags: office365, office-addins, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I have assigned `Office.initialize` a function to initialize my outlook add-in however it's never called and I verified this by using console.log() statements. When I opened my developer console, I got this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: context" (refer to screenshot). This runtime error happens 75% of the time but this never happened a week ago.

Could this be a transient error?

I'm using Chrome 51.0.2704.106 and Office 365's Outlook (web app).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This error was completely my fault. I accidentally referenced Outlook's Javascript file (ie: `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`) twice. After removing one of the references, the error disappeared.

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined` I'm referring to `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript">`